# Jquery html() function too slow

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(".induction-group").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function(event) {
    $(this).trigger("currentPosition", function( page ) {
        number_of_claims = $(this).find(".claim").length;
            element = $(this).find('.induction-claim-counter').first();
            element.html("Example # " + (page+1) + "/" + number_of_claims);
    });
 });
```

This works ok in chrome, but totally freezes firefox and IE

.induction-group content

```
<div class="row claim-depth-<%#= claim.depth - root_claim.depth %>"> 
<div class="claim">
    <div class="claim-id"> <%= claim.id %> </div>   
    <div class="col-xs-1 claim-icon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 claim-text hidden-sm hidden-xs induction-claim-text">
            <div class="induction-background-1"></div>
            <div class="induction-background-2"></div>
            <div class="induction-background-3"></div>
            <div class="prev-claim">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left">
            </div>
            <div class="next-claim">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right">
            </div>
            <div class="induction-claim-counter"> <-- !!!!!!! -->
            </div>
            <%= claim.text %>   
    </div>
...............
```

text() and val() functions don't work at all.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely creating a race condition....since you are modifying the DOM within an event handler that watches DOM changes. Perhaps you might get alternatives if you explained why you are using it

Read the Red disclimer in [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/DOMSubtreeModified)

**`Be very careful with this event it is easy to cause an infinite loop if you decide to change the DOM inside the event handler.`**

Comment: Thanks, at least I know a problem now. I have a carousel, and I need to update page counter avery time a slide changes.

Comment: I'm using caroufredSel plugin, it seem it doen't have an event for that.

Comment: never used plugin but I see a `onAfter`and `onBefore` callbacks in docs you can use. Both return map data of state

Answer (score 0):

Maybe  jquerys .append () ?
I'm not 100% sure